# Azure get-access-token: How long is token valid

Tags: azure-devops

I have a CI/CD Pipeline which uses [get-access-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-account-get-access-token) to get a token for Databricks. In the docu it is stated:

> The token will be valid for at least 5 minutes with the maximum at 60
> minutes. If the subscription argument isn't specified, the current
> account is used.

However, my pipeline will take longer than 5 minutes. How can I check if the token is still valid? It seems like I can't set the duration so I plan to get a new one if the old one is not valid any more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get-access-token returns when the token expires

[image]